# lavaan - problems with WLSMV estimator

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am running a SEM using lavaan that includes 5 latent variables. Also, I have 5 regression equations (Y~...) where outcomes are manifest variables and regressors are a mix of latents and indicators.

When I use maximum likelihood estimation the model runs without problem. But when I switch to **WLSMV** estimation (adding the argument *estimator = "WLSMV"*) I am finding two problems. The first problem is that the execution becomes extremely slow taking several hours to run a single model, any idea why this is happening and if there is a way to fix it?

The second problem is that when I try to fit multigroup SEMs and start constraining the model I get the following warning:

```
lavaan WARNING: the optimizer (NLMINB) claimed the model converged,
                but not all elements of the gradient are (near) zero;
                the optimizer may not have found a local solution
                use check.gradient = FALSE to skip this check.
```

Any idea what this means? what are the implications? is this a problem? how I fix it? should I simply stay with maximum likelihood?

**IMPORTANT:** when I remove the regressions and keep only the measurement part (the five latent variables) the function execute fast and I stop getting the warning message. Does it mean that WLSMV should not be used when the CFA becomes a SEM?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are asking specific questions associated with `lavaan` package. I would suggest you posting this question in `lavaan` google group (https://groups.google.com/g/lavaan). My experience was they usually responded very quickly.@Orlando Sabogal

Answer (score 1):

You have a big model for a small sample, I bet, and particularly small for the DWLS estimator with a mean- and variance-adjusted (MV) chi-squared test statistic... WLSMV. You can try to simplify your model, increase your sample, or use a different estimator, like the "MLR" maximum likelihood estimation with robust (Huber– White) standard errors.

I suggest that you check the chapter by Finney, DiStefano, and Kopp (2016).

S.J. Finney, C. DiStefano, J.P. Kopp. Overview of estimation methods and preconditions for their application with structural equation modeling K. Schweizer, C. DiStefano (Eds.), Principles and methods of test construction: Standards and recent advances, Hogrefe Publishing, Boston, MA, USA (2016), pp. 135-165, [10.1027/00449-000](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334710008_Overview_of_estimation_methods_and_preconditions_for_their_application_with_structural_equation_modeling)

Comment: Thanks for your response! My sample size is about 6000.

Comment: How many degrees of freedom do you have in your model?

Comment: I have 725 degrees of freedom.